# hourglass issue on firefox when switching tabs

Tags: ajax, jsf, icefaces

I have a very strange problem in my web application.

I am using **icefaces** with **jsf** and on some of my pages (please do not ask for the code because it's a lot of it:) **I see the hourglass effect appearing on firefox.**

I can clearly confirm that is because, somehow, the jsf cycle is not entirely finished. (*all the components are visible but validation is not working*).

Please note that this issue **does not appear if I press F5** but only when I switch some tabs, which basically change the content of the main form)...

Are you guys having any suggestion? Google did not help me...nor Firebug...

**UPDATE**:
- after further investigation with Firebug it seems that when I do an ajax POST, it does not load the scripts and css which are inside the `<body> </body>` (you will see in the answer why it puts some css and scripts here) tag...but only the ones from `<head>...</head>`

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved!!! (please see my update before continuing reading this answer)

I had this code in my main template:

```
<head>
<ui:include
    src="/WEB-INF/jsf/common/templates/main/commonResources-include.xhtml" />
</head>
```

Now please note that commonResources-include.xhtml has this code (please note html tags!)

```
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

..code..
</html>
```

**It seems that whenever you use these facelets components to be included, templating etc you MUST use** `<ui:composition>` tags and not `<html>`, because html tags will confuse the rendering engine of the browser! What is strange is that a lot of examples from the internet use html tags for these facelets which do not give issues in helloWorld examples but can be a pain in complex applications!

So, the final code:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
..code..
</ui:composition>
```